# How can I update a column for a given row based on the results of a select statement?

Tags: postgresql

Sorry that the question title doesn't explain my problem well:

Say I have a table, Dog:

| ID | Name | Breed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fido | Mutt |
| 2 | Lassie | Collie |
| .. | ... | .. |
| 999 | Spot | Dalmation |

I then realized that it would be better to have a separate "Breed" table:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mutt |
| 2 | Lassie |
| 3 | Dalmation |

So now, I can add a "breedId" column to the Dog table, but how do I set those values?

Essentially I want to do this:  `update Dog [for row N] set breedId = (select id from Breed where name = [row N's breed])`

But I don't know how to translate the parts in `[]` into SQL, or what to search for.  I figure this is a fairly common problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the Dalmatian name in the Breed table is supposed to be ID 999 and not 3?

I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE Dog, Breed 
SET [Dog].[BreedID] = [Breed].[Name]
WHERE (([Dog].[ID]=[Breed].[ID]));
```

The output of this would be a Dog table looking like:

```
ID  Name    BreedID
1   Fido    Mutt
2   Lassie  Lassie
999 Spot    Dalmatian
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the dogs table to reference to the new breeds table is actually a relative simple query: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6fbd8ebe7bcf05a79d0fbf3d9545cec2))

```
-- update dogs with breed_id 
update dogs d 
   set breed_id = b.breed_id 
  from breeds b 
 where b.name = d.breed;
```

Beyond that you actions should followup with:

- make the new breedid required and FK to the breed table
- remove the unnecessary breed column from dogs